# Using Visual Studio for open source projects (projects management & legal issues)

Tags: visual-studio

1. I'm working on small open source
   project for developed Windows. I
   created new project using Visual
   Studio wizard and now I want to
   publish it using subversion and
   develop it with friends. What
   projects' configuration files I have
   to add to repository to make my
   friends able to download current
   project's revision and open it in
   Visual Studio?

   2. List item
      University where I study is a member
      of Microsoft Academy Alliance
      project, which make students able to
      download legal copies of many
      Microsoft's products. Can I use this
      copy to develop open source project
      and publish created code in
      Internet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For 1; I would exclude *.user and *.suo files as they are user-specific, and the bin/obj folders as they are build **output**. Include most everything else; .cs, .csproj, .resx, etc.

For 2, [from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/academic/bb250622.aspx):

> You may use the software for
>   non-commercial purposes including
>   instructional use, research and/or
>   design, and development and testing of
>   projects for class assignments, tests,
>   or personal projects. You may not use
>   MSDNAA software for any for-profit
>   software development.

I'm not a lawyer, but as long as you aren't selling it you should be fine under the "personal projects" caveat.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you could always use free alternatives:

[Sharp Develop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/) (also open source)

[Visual Studio 2010 Express Editions](http://www.microsoft.com/express/downloads/)

This allows other users, perhaps hobbyists, to have access.  Legally you should be fine, don't sell it though.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the restrictions for not selling a license placed by Microsoft is not copacetic to the GPL license.  You cannot therefore fork a GPL project and use Visual Studio for your project build. This [article](http://www.pcworld.com/article/256339/microsoft_delivers_a_blow_to_open_source_with_visual_studio_11.html) is rather telling of the issues. The [blog post](http://stephenhaunts.com/2014/04/03/develop-open-source-alternative-to-visual-studio/) gives Sharp Develop high praises as an alternative solution.